# Extracting specific words from middle of string without using startwith function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops

I am trying to extract the names of variables from the list. I have declared a list as list_end, and in the for loop, I want for loop to read each string in the list, and if "int" is found in the string, then it start from the int and end with the list_end, and add to the empty list_variable

```html
def custom_endswith(d, list_end):
    for end_pattern in list_end:
        if d.endswith(end_pattern):
            return True
    return False

list_end = ["=",";",")","("]
list_variable = []

data = ["int zt;",
  "public int w = 3;",
  "public final int nu;public a(d dVar, int i, int i2);",
  "public int getScoreOrder() {int getInteger;",
  "for (int i = 0; i < this.nu; i++)",
  "{public a(d dVar, int t) {super(dVar, i);",
  "private int z = true ;if (getType() != 1) {z = false;",
  "protected int g = true;",
  "unprotected int z = true;if (getType() != 1) {z = false;",
  "public int getType() {return getInteger();",
  "int y;",
  "print (int i) {int k = b.k(parcel);"]

for d in data:
    if d.startswith("int") and custom_endswith(d, list_end):
        list_variable.append(d[4:-1])
```

But my script only extracts the those variable names, where string with "int". And when "int" comes in the middle of the string, it does not extract words. Is this because I used the.startwith function in script? If not, what other function can I use to extract variable names from the middle of a string?

```html
Output of my script:
print(list_variable)
Output: ['zt', 'y']
```

In fact, it should give output like:

```html
print(list_variable)
Output: ['zt','w','nu','i','i2','getScoreOrder','getInteger','i','t','z','g','z','getType','y','i','k']
```

Comment: To check if string `a` contains string `b`, do `if b in a`. `startswith` does exactly what the name says, which is apparently not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with regex

```py
import re

regex = re.compile('int\s+([^=;:\(\)]+)') # capture characters after int and space (must occur at least once) which is not a character in line_ends


result = []
for line in data:
    result.extend(regex.findall(line))
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is because you used the `.startswith()` and `.endswith()` methods, which only check if the **entire string** starts with the input parameter string. You can check if a string contains another string like this:

```py
for d in data:
    if "int" in d and ... :
        ...
```

If you are doing custom string extractions anyways, you could use [RegEx](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), which automatically parses the string for you:

```
int\s(\w+)\s*[=;\)\(]
```

- Match `int`
- Match whitespace between `int` and the next part (like a space)
- Match the variable/function name
- Match any one of these characters: `=;)(`

Then you can use it in the code like this:

```py
import re

re.findall(r"int\s(\w+)\s*[=;\)\(]", "public int getScoreOrder() {int getInteger;")
```

One final note though- it appears you're trying to parse Java code. Maybe try using a proper Java parser library instead, which can do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried it, and it is working well but it doesn't extract variables which end before " =".

Comment: @yaxier I added a blank whitespace match in my edit. It should work now. If my answer is correct, feel free to click the check mark and maybe give me an upvote :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I am new to stack overflow. Let me check, how can I upvote. and thanks again you saved a whole day effort.

Answer (score 1):

Using *re* is probably the best way to do this - with one caveat. Your list_end characters will be embedded in the *re* pattern. If you ever needed to change the "list end" characters then you risk breaking the pattern (unless you're very familiar with regular expressions).

It might be useful to show a step-wise approach without *re* or, indeed, any other imports. (Note - to get the required output you need a comma in the list_end set)

```
list_end = set('=;)(,')

data = ["int zt;",
  "public int w = 3;",
  "public final int nu;public a(d dVar, int i, int i2);",
  "public int getScoreOrder() {int getInteger;",
  "for (int i = 0; i < this.nu; i++)",
  "{public a(d dVar, int t) {super(dVar, i);",
  "private int z = true ;if (getType() != 1) {z = false;",
  "protected int g = true;",
  "unprotected int z = true;if (getType() != 1) {z = false;",
  "public int getType() {return getInteger();",
  "int y;",
  "print (int i) {int k = b.k(parcel);"]

INT = 'int'

vnames = []

for line in data:
    offset = 0
    while (o := line[offset:].find(INT)) >= 0:
        vname = []
        offset += o + len(INT)
        for i in line[offset:]:
            if not i.isspace():
                if i in list_end:
                    break
                vname.append(i)
        if vname:
            vnames.append(vname)

print(*[''.join(v) for v in vnames])
```

**Output:**

```
zt w nu i i2 getScoreOrder getInteger i t z g z getType y i k
```

**Note:**

The *isspace()* test is there to allow for multiple whitespace between 'int' and the variable name. The code can be simplified if it's reasonable to assume that there's exactly one space between those two tokens

Comment: Thank you so much. It has worked too. thanks again. cheers