# Replacing a string of list with another list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have two lists, and I am trying to replace words in the list of strings and I am trying to add to an empty list.

```
 data = ["int zt;",
    "public int w = ;",
    "public final int nu;public a(d dVar, int i, int i2);",
    "public int getScoreOrder() {int getInteger;",
    "for (int i = 0; i < this.nu; i++)",
    "{public a(d dVar, int t) {super(dVar, i);",
    "private int z = true ;if (getType() != 1) {z = false;",
    "protected int g = true;",
    "unprotected int z = true;if (getType() != 1) {z = false;",
    "public int getType) {return getInteger();",
    "int y;",
    "print (int i) {int k = b.k(parcel);"]



data_variable = ['zt', 'w', 'nu', 'i2', 'getScoreOrder', 'getInteger', 'i', 't', 'z', 'g', 'z', 'getType', 'y', 'i', 'k']
lis = []
data_variable = [*set(data_variable)]
print(type(lis))
for i in data_variable:
    for d in data:
        if i in d:
            s = d.replace(i," data_variable ")
            lis.append(s)
print(lis)
```

This small script is taking each item from list `data_variable` and checking with the each item of list `data` and if it contains item of `data_variable`, it just replaces it with `"data_variable"`. And appending it to the empty list (`lis`).

There are 12 items in a list (`data`) and my script appends 48 items in list (`lis`). In fact list (`lis`) should contain 12 items.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You will need something more sophisticated than this. For example, if you search the strings for 'i' there are multiple occurrences and you wouldn't want to replace everything that matches. Look at the first element of your *data* list. There's 'i' in there but you would want to replace that. Look at the answer(s) given to your earlier question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74918324/extracting-specific-words-from-middle-of-string-without-using-startwith-function) and adapt that

Comment: You need to copy the data list to the empty list and then iterate through the empty list and [replace the characters](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-replace-multiple-characters-in-string) with the new characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are several problems:

- You should loop over the 'data' list first
- You should append the new element only after you have done all replacements
- The tricky part is that you want to replace word that are in fact letter. For example your replace function will replace every 'i' by 'data_variable'. You only want to do that if there is a space before of after the letter 'i', otherwise a word like 'public' will become 'publdata_variablec'. Maybe using a regular expression would help (https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), or you can just have ' i' and 'i ' in your data_variable list.

Something last this should work:

```
    result = []
    data_variable = ['zt', 'nu', 'i2', 'getScoreOrder', 'getInteger',  'getType','i ', ' i']
    data_variable = [*set(data_variable)]
    for d in data:
        for i in data_variable:
            d = d.replace(i," data_variable ")
        result.append(d)

    print(result)
    print(len(result))
```

Also to remove duplicate I would just use:

```
    data_variable = list(set(['zt', 'nu', 'i2', 'getScoreOrder', 'getInteger',  'getType','i ', ' i']))
```