# Extract words from the list which meet certain conditions using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, python-re

I am trying to extract words from the list that meet certain conditions. It should read each line and if the line ends with ")" and in that line it should extract words starting from "." and " " space and end to "(".

I know I can't use the startwith and endwith functions because there are no certain startwith words. That is why I am using re library, but still, my script is not executing.

```html
import re
data = ["int k = b.k(parcel)",
"int k = kon(parcel)",
"int a", 
"int bds",
"obtain.appendFrom(parcel, dataPosition2, readInt2)",
"obtain desFrom(package, dataPosition2, readInt2)",
"int abd(callme)",
"int.dbd(callyou)",
"int throw new UnsupportedOperationException(you)",
"int throw new.UnsupportedOperationException(me)"]

for i in data:
    para = re.findall(r"*[ \.]\s(\w+)\s*[)]" ,i) # start from space and dot and endwith ")"
    i = i.replace(para,"function_call")
    
for i in data:
    print(i)
```

I want output like :

```html
int k = b.function_call(parcel)
int k = function_call(parcel)
int a 
int bds
obtain.function_call(parcel, dataPosition2, readInt2)
obtain function_call(package, dataPosition2, readInt2)
int function_call(callme)
int.function_call(callyou)
int throw new function_call(you)
int throw new.function_call(me)
```

Comment: This is a continuation of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74921438/replacing-a-string-of-list-with-another-list and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74918324/extracting-specific-words-from-middle-of-string-without-using-startwith-function You really need to make up your mind what you're hoping to achieve and consolidate into just one question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `re.sub` to use a regexp to replace a segment. You can't use the return value of `findall` as an argument to `str.replace` in the first place, and doing `i = i.replace(...)` will not modify the `i` in the list (since strings are immutable for one).

So, here's a version that uses a list comprehension to run a regexp replacement on all strings to result in a new list:

```
import re

data = [
    "int k = b.k(parcel)",
    "int k = kon(parcel)",
    "int a",
    "int bds",
    "obtain.appendFrom(parcel, dataPosition2, readInt2)",
    "obtain desFrom(package, dataPosition2, readInt2)",
    "int abd(callme)",
    "int.dbd(callyou)",
    "int throw new UnsupportedOperationException(you)",
    "int throw new.UnsupportedOperationException(me)",
]

fixed_data = [
    re.sub(r"(\w+)\s*\(", "function_call(", i)
    for i in data
]

for i in fixed_data:
    print(i)
```